# How to pass Authentication Header in Flutter WebSocketChannel?

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

I'm using Flutter **web_socket_channel** package to communicate with server. The class `WebSocketChannel` doesn't take a header parameter.

```
factory WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri uri, {Iterable<String>? protocols}) =>
      platform.connect(uri, protocols: protocols);
```

When using `IOWebSocketChannel` to pass header, I'm getting `Unsupported operation: Platform._version` in web like given [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45982#issue-531938119). It is working fine in Android and iOS.

Answer (score 2):

The concise answer is: **No because only the path in your URI and protocol field can be set up**.

Longer answer:
In the pure JS [WebSocket API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#network), there is no method to specify extra headers for the browser to send.

You can specify only

```
GET query(was://mysockets.com/path)
```

and header protocol called `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol`

**Conclusion**: If you can't achieve such functionality in the native code then this functionality is unavailable for your flutter web app

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

#### Totally possible with a Flutter client and Rust server

It is inaccurate to state that it is not possible to authenticate users. The solution is to share the bearerToken and check the authentication with some extra-code on the server side.

How can we pass the relevant data to the server? Two ways to do it:

#### 1/ Disabling initial auth check

We remove AuthUser (axum) parameter in the websocket endpoint in both cases:

```rs
pub(crate) async fn websocket_handler(
    Path((roomId)): Path<String>,
    //    auth_user: AuthUser,
    ws: WebSocketUpgrade,
    State(state): State<ApiContext>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {
   let my_room_uuid = Uuid::parse_str(&roomId).unwrap();
   ws.on_upgrade(move |socket| websocket(socket, state, my_room_uuid))
}
```

#### 2/a/ Using url args (if we only care about sharing the bearerToken)

Pass the bearer token in the url so:

```dart
url = '$websocketEndpoint/$roomId';
channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(url));
```

becomes

```dart
url = '$websocketEndpoint/$roomId/$bearerToken';
channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(url));
```

#### 2/b/ With websocket's initial message

We send the bearer token in the very first message, before the main websocket loop, and after the websocket connection has been upgraded, so adding to initState:

```dart
url = '$websocketEndpoint/$roomId';
channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(url));
String token = {your bearer token, obtained from user login};
channel.sink.add("Bearer $token");
```

A simplified example of a Rust axum backend before/after:

```rs
async fn websocket(stream: WebSocket, state: ApiContext, roomId: Uuid) {
    let (mut sender, mut receiver) = stream.split();
    let mut rx = state.tx.subscribe();
    let tx = state.tx.clone();
```

becomes:

```rs
async fn websocket(stream: WebSocket, state: ApiContext, roomId: Uuid) {
    let (mut sender, mut receiver) = stream.split();
    let mut rx = state.tx.subscribe();
    let tx = state.tx.clone();

    let mut auth_user: AuthUser;
    if let Some(Ok(Message::Text(text))) = receiver.next().await {
        let auth_header: HeaderValue = HeaderValue::from_str(&text).unwrap();
        auth_user = AuthUser::from_authorization(&state, &auth_header).unwrap();

        <now check that the auth_user token is valid, if not return error 403 forbidden>
```